# How can I make elements on my webpage automatically update when it's MySQL database changes?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've created the following PHP code to produce a feed of all the comments in my MySQL database.

```
<?

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename");

if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0 , 1000";

$comments = mysqli_query($con, $query);

echo "<h1>Recent Posts</h1><br><br><hr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($comments, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $comment = $row['comment'];
  $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
  $comment = htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES);
  $score = $row['score'];
  $id = $row['id'];

  echo " <div class='card'>
      <p>$comment</p><br />
      <p>Post #$id</p>
      <p>Score: $score</p><br>
      <button onclick='myfunction($id,1)'>Upvote</button><button onclick='myfunction($id,-1)'>Downvote</button><br>
      <p style='color: grey'>$timestamp</p><hr>
    </div>
  ";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

It is included within a HTML file which contains the following js script:

```
function myfunction(postid,vote){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'addvote.php',
    data: {vote: vote, postid: postid, score: $("#postscore").val()},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});

}
```

Where the file addvote.php is given by the following code:

```
<?php

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

    $vote = $_POST['vote'];
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $userid = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT score FROM database.table WHERE id ='$postid'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $score = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['score']);

    $newscore = $score + $vote;

  $query1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE postid='$postid' AND ipaddress='$userid'");

  $numi = mysqli_num_rows($query1);

if($numi == 0){

  $query3 = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`postid`, `ipaddress`, `vote`, `id`) VALUES ('$postid', '$userid', '$vote', NULL)";

  mysqli_query($con, $query3);

  $sql = "UPDATE `database`.`table` SET `score` = '$newscore' WHERE `mainfeed`.`id` = '$postid'";

  mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  echo "Thanks for voting!";

  }

  else {

  echo "You have already voted on post number ".$postid;

  }

  mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This all works fine when it comes up upvoteing and downvoting posts - it makes the change to the post score in the MySQL database without refreshing the webpage. However, it does not change the score shown on the webpage until the page is reloaded. How can I make it so that changes in the score are immediately displayed on the webpage, without needing to refresh it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PHP is not well suited for such a task. You definitely have to combine it with some client side logic, so javascript: Upon load you fire a "long polling" ajax call or open a "websocket" to the server, both serve the same goal: on the server side you poll for changes on a regular base and relay that change back to the calling client sides. Then, again on the client side, you can update the already loaded page.

Comment: Instead of `alert(data);` update the DOM with the updated data. You should use parameterized queries; this is open to SQL injections as is.

Comment: Could I make a second client side script that increments/deincriments the score value on the page? I mean, instead of updating the score when the MySQL database updates, could I make the score change when the button is pressed instead (using js)?

Comment: I think uou must use NODEJS insted of php. in nodejs you can pool data into client with server and have a long time connection. ** https://nodejs.org/en/ **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem by changing the value of the variable `data` in the php script to the new value of the posts score. I've then used

```
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = data;
```

So that the client side value changes to the value in the MySQL database, without having to fetch it.